# How can I rearrange an array of items into 3 columns with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, matrix

I have an array of menu items that I'm printing out to the screen using a foreach loop into a single, continuous, unordered list.  Because of CSS/design, they display on the screen in 3 columns in this order...

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

But I need them to display like this...

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

Is there a way I can, without changing the HTML structure and still within a single for/foreach loop, print out the same items so that they are arranged in the latter configuration?

Example code

```
<ul>
     <?php  
         foreach($nav_menu as $nav):
             echo "<li><a href='" . $nav->url . "'>" . $nav->title . "</a></li>";
         endforeach;
     ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: As far as i understand, you probably need at least two foreach loops to print out the shown structure. Please show the whole code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<ul>
     <?php  
         foreach($nav_menu as $index => $nav):
             $array_index = ($index / 3) + 3 * ($index % 3);
             echo "<li><a href='" . $nav_menu[$array_index]->url . "'>" . $nav_menu[$array_index]->title . "</a></li>";
         endforeach;
     ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, I had to make a few minor additions to make this more generalized, but you did provide the answer to the exact question I was asking and it lead me to the formula I needed, so it still counts.

Answer (score 0):

Gives you want you say you want... :)

```
    $n = 1;$t=0;
for($l=1;$l<=9;++$l){
echo $n; ++$t;  

    if($t==3){
        $n=($n-5); 
        echo '<br>';
        $t=0;
            }
    else{
        $n = $n + 3;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this more generalized solution for future reference, and it's based on x01saa's answer, which is still the correct one given the question I asked.

```
             <?php
                $cols = 3; // this could be any positive integer
                $rows = ceil((float)count($nav_menu)/(float)$cols);

                foreach($nav_menu as $index => $nav):
                    $array_index = ($index / $cols) + $rows * ($index % $cols);
                    echo "<li><a href='" . $nav_menu[$array_index]->url . "'>" . $nav_menu[$array_index]->title . "</a></li>";
                endforeach;
              ?>
```